# With CSS, how to force responsive shop to continue displaying 2 columns in the shop under 400px of res?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a resonsive website build with wordpress and woocommerce (https://oliv-collection.com/). Under 400 px, the store (at the bottom of the page) is displayed with juts 1 column instead of 2. What additional CSS can I add to avoid that from happening, and continue to show 2 columns even in low res devices?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @media queries into your CSS.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  your-column {
    width: 50%; (You can try different sizes.)
  }
}
```

Take a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thank you, but that code does not seem to be working, it is unclear what "your-column" should be in my case

Comment: In your case, your-column should be your column tag, class or id.